# There's an egg file at the top of my sys.path - how can I get rid of it?

Tags: python-3.x, path

I noticed my jupyter notebooks started having problems; I discovered there was a problem with duplicate IPython in my path.

Doing some research, it looks like up until today my dist-packages was:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
```

now, it's:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
```

a little more research shows that my path got messed up, and there's an egg file on the top:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print("\n".join(sys.path))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.34.dev0-py3.5.egg
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python35.zip
/usr/lib/python3.5
/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
/home/veggiebenz/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

I'd like to find out where this is getting added.  There's no PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Also, the final entry (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages) I would like to get it back to being the first entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out, so I'm posting this here in case someone else has the same issue.

Turns out there was a .pth file that was prepending these items to sys.path.

From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html):

> A path configuration file is a file whose name has the form name.pth
>   and exists in one of the four directories mentioned above; its
>   contents are additional items (one per line) to be added to sys.path

In any event, here's what I did to fix it.

```
sudo locate easy-install.pth
```

Found it here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
```

I opened this file in text editor and commented out the lines referring to the egg file and to the incorrect dist-packages folder.  Then a reboot to give everything a fresh start.  Now my python environment is happy and my jupyter notebooks are working correctly.